# clients auto-lock feature for inactvity timeout not working

Tags: display, windows-sbs-2011

In our `sbs 2003` domain environment, the clients' pc's inactive for default period will be locked out automatically and only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> & client  password combination will unlock the client's pcs.

Recently around 9 months before, all our client's pc's joined the new `sbs 2011` but  (usually all are locking with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> key combination manually)the auto lock feature is not working from the beginning onwards. Now only I am brought up with this issue by clients.

Please help me set that option!

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved with the help from

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/smallbusinessserver/thread/f0c09ea5-dc2f-4d5a-b296-911e90a88522